# laravel How to get the table's column value in model and re-use in where

Tags: laravel

There are three tables:

1. sys_session: id, oid, ... and other columns
2. user: id, ...
3. member: id,...

sys_session's oid means both user_id(negative) or member_id(positive).

If oid = 5, it's positive number, so it means member_id = 5
If oid = -5, it's negative number, so it means user_id  = 5

How to define the user() relationship?

```
class SysSession extends Model
{
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Member::class, 'id', 'oid');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Member::class, 'id', 'oid')
                    ->where('oid', abs(xxx));
    }
}
```

What should I write in user's where() ?

Comment: 1. your relation here should be `belongsTo` rather than `hasOne`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

2. quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.. maybe you're looking for a polymorphic relationship instead: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: I edited the content. I want to get relation: $sys_session->user. The database and website is already online. I cannot change it. Just to create a new admin system.

Comment: looks very brittle to be honest, but if you cannot change the structure then you could try to add `where('oid', '<', 0)` for one and `where('oid', '>', 0)` for the other.

Comment: That's a good solution!

Comment: If it solved your problem I'll post as an answer so you can accept and mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: sorry, your solution doesn't work. If I get a sys_session, and the oid= -5, and it will use -5 to find in the member table. So we must use abs().

Comment: oh this part will not work for sure in eloquent. It's simply bad design of the SQL table. There is no relation setup that would work here (you may make it work by using `abs` in PHP, but there is still a lot going on on the SQL level that will fail eventually, even if a case with single model does work sometimes `$sysSession->user`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is $this->oid. a simple anwser.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Member::class, 'id', 'oid')
                ->where('id', abs($this->oid));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Member::class, 'oid', 'id')
                    ->where('oid', '>', 0);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Member::class, 'oid', 'id')
                    ->where('oid', '<', 0);
    }
```